# How to know which firewall is used?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

System is ubuntu. `gufw` was not installed and after I installed it then shows firewall is disabled. But firewall IS definitely there.

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu, you can type `sudo iptables -L` to see the active firewall rules.